# Titanium Alloy LeftNavButton not showing up in simulator

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

Not sure where I am doing wrong. I tried via code and by xml, but for some reason the left nav button does not show up. I am using the simulator since I don't have an actual device for ios.

The xml view

```
<!--filename: playType.xml->
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <LeftNavButton platform="ios">
            <Button title="Back" onClick="closeWindow"/>    
        </LeftNavButton>
        <View class="buttonContainer">
            <Button class="menuButton" title="Single Player"/>
            <Button class="menuButton" title ="Duel"/>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

The Controller

```
//playType.js
var args = arguments[0] || {};

var closeWindow = function(){
    $.playType.close();
};
```

The tss style

```
//playType.tss
".container" : {
  backgroundColor:"white",
  height:Ti.UI.FILL,
},
".buttonContainer":{
    center:{x:"50%",y:"50%"},
    height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
    layout:"vertical"   
}
```

I using this from the index.js

```
var playType = Alloy.createController('playType').getView();
playType.open();
```

The window shows up fine with the two buttons in the center but the back button doesn't appear.
What am I doing wrong. I went through the doc and also tried the code way too. Same result, no back button. :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the window using navigation window otherwise navButton wont show up.here goes the code link for you

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your window must be placed inside a [TabGroup](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup) which handles all the capabilities of a navigation controller inside each tab.

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup>
        <Tab id="tab1" title="Tab 1">
            <Window id="win1" title="Tab 1">
                <LeftNavButton platform="ios">
                   <Button title="Back" onClick="closeWindow"/>    
                </LeftNavButton>
               ...
            </Window>
        </Tab>
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

As for the back button, open a child window of the current tab using the tab as the reference to the open method.

```
tab.open(newWindow);
```